# how to analyze threads in eclipse blackberry project?

Tags: multithreading, eclipse, blackberry

I am creating a multithreaded application.. but it drains battery. whether i want to check what are the threads running and memory leaks etc..

is there any tool or plugin to check thread activity in my eclipse for blackberry application..

sorry for asking this here, please guide me where to post such questions and tell me solution for this..

Answer (score 4):

If you're an Eclipse user, the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse 1.3 does come with BlackBerry Memory Statistics View, Objects View and Profiler View. I've had success with that and 1.3.0 fixes an issue with debugging on the actual device.